ElasticSearch phrase_prefix not working in specific index
I have a large index with the following structure and documents like:
{
  "_index": "resources",
  "_type": "TEST",
  "_id": "29665b5f-18f6-4819-b24e-45ccc290132d",
  "_score": 568.1415,
  "_source": {
    "material": {
      "question": "El Parlamento Europeo tiene en la actualidad los siguientes Diputado"
    }
  }
}

When I run a query with ending in t, it doesn't return docs:
GET resources/_search
{
    "_source": ["material.question"],
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "fields": [
        "material.question"
      ],
      "query": "El Parlamento Europeo t",
      "type": "phrase_prefix"
    }
  }
}

But, when running with ti, it does:
GET resources/_search
{
  "_source": ["material.question"],
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "fields": [
        "material.question"
      ],
      "query": "El Parlamento Europeo ti",
      "type": "phrase_prefix"
    }
  }
}

I've created a new index and loaded some documents to check it and works well with both queries (ending with t and ti).
I've tried using the spanish analyzer too but got the same result.
Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Which analyzer do you use?

@murak the default one

If you are not having this issue with a new index, its possible something is up with your current mapping. Any chance you can post that?
